# How to Save Words in Array

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist

I am making a school project which is about restaurant menu.
I have to save all of my items name separately in an array, and their price in different array.

Output should be something like this:

```
 1. Burger  19.2
 2. Fries   21.21
 ....
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TOTALITEM 3
int main()
{
    const char *menu[TOTALITEM] = {"Burger", "Fries", "wings"};
    double menuPrice[TOTALITEM] = {19.2, 21.21, 51.2};
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTALITEM; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%i. %c", i+1,menu[i]);
        printf("\t\t %.2lf", menuPrice[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `%c` to `%-8s`.

Comment: You would be wise to read your C text book or tutorials.

Comment: ... and remove the `\t\t ` from the next line. Move the `\n` from the start of the first format string to the end of the second format string.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using a pointer array first you have to allocate memory size of your word or string. use stdlib.h library and the malloc() function.

```
char *menu[TOTALITEM];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < TOTALITEM; i++)
{
     menu[i] = (char*) malloc(size_of_word);
}

menu[0] = "Burger";
menu[1] = "Fries";
menu[3] = "wings";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `%c` to `%-8s`.
                    – Weather Vane